# maui app is crashing when I install it on any android device

Tags: .net, apk, maui

Maui apps crash when you build the .apk file and install them on any android devices,
no matter what the contents of the app are, startup project/samples.

I checked the offical docs, generated a keystore and added the mentioned tags inside .csproj file
[offical doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0)
I used these commands

> dotnet publish/dotnet build followed by the targeted framework
> with different configurations set: degbug/release.

Everytime I got two .apk files, one of them was unsigned and the android device couldn't parse that package so it can't be installed, and the other one is signed and you could install the app, but it crashes when you open it.
I am not sure if I'm missing something else?

- log report [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AmZv.png)

- only one file in assembiles folder named rc.BIN and it contains:

> MMicrosoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.VerifyOpenGenericServiceTrimmabilitytrue"System.AggressiveAttributeTrimmingtrue2System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.IsSupportedfalseSystem.Globalization.Invariantfalse)System.Net.Http.EnableActivityPropagationfalse$System.Net.Http.UseNativeHttpHandlertrue4System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupportedfalse<System.Runtime.InteropServices.BuiltInComInterop.IsSupportedfalseESystem.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerializationfalse&System.StartupHookProvider.IsSupportedfalse-System.Text.Encoding.EnableUnsafeUTF7Encodingfalse

Comment: What do the device logs show?  Have you run a debug build on the device?  Have you tried any crash reporting tools?

Comment: I can't enable developer mode on those devices but I did use android studio to debug the apk, updated the questione and you should find an image on the crash report

Comment: Please do not post text logs in a screen shot. `Make sure that all entries in the APK directory named 'assemblies/' are STORED (not compressed)` have you checked that? Open APK in ZIP tool like 7-ip and check the compression state of each entry.

Comment: @Robert okay, here it is what's inside the folder. I updated the question, what should I do next?

Comment: @Kirollos The content of the folder is not relevant, you should check that inside the APK file those entries are not compressed (compression method "stored"). That is what the error message tells you.

Comment: @Robert sorry my bad, I'm confused. what should I check for inside the apk?

Comment: @Kirollos as I wrote open the APK in 7-Zip and check all entries in the mentioned folder and subfolders for their compression type used.

Comment: @Robert in assemblies and most of the directories the comperssion method is store, other directories like kotlin and lib and .dex files the comperssion method is deflate or deflate:maximum

Comment: Do other apps also have this problem? How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Did I try to build another .apk file for another app? yes, same problem. I did go through the steps provided by the link, which basically descibe generating a signed apk.

Comment: You can try to [repair your visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) and try again.